# Grunt error and blank page on `sails lift`

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I followed the (extremely simple) instructions here: http://sailsjs.org/get-started.

However, when I tried running `sails lift` it just gave me a blank page because I had a problem with my grunt install.  I reinstalled it, which fixed the errors, but now I still have a blank page when I visit `localhost:1337`.  I know *something* is working, because when I stop running `sails lift` I don't even get a blank page, but I'm not seeing the expected `homepage.ejs`.

My output when I run `sails lift` is:

```
sails lift
info: Starting app...

info: 
info:                .-..-.
info: 
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.11.0             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------'
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `C:\Users\Me\WebstormProjects\GameWorldCraft`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: --------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Sat Aug 22 2015 12:24:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
info: Gruntfile could not be found.
info: (no grunt tasks will be run.)
```

Those last two lines seem like they're the problem, but I have no idea how to fix them.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out this was just a human stupidity issue.  For future reference, if you fail to `cd` in to the `newProject` directory (or, in my case, you `cd` in to it then back out to fix a Grunt issue) then you will get:

```
info: Gruntfile could not be found.
info: (no grunt tasks will be run.)
```

and a blank page.  Solution?  `cd testProject`.

Comment: I guess you get to mark your own answer as the right one.  :laugh:

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your sails install failed for some reason.

```
npm uninstall sails
npm cache clear
npm install sails
```

If that doesn't work go into your app/node_modules/sails directory and then run:

```
npm install grunt-cli
```

(In some cases, you might have already had the grunt CLI installed globally and it gets in the way.)

Comment: I needed to do that earlier because of a sails problem, but it turned out that in this case I just missed a (key) step.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue like this, at the end these two lines are showing

```
info: Gruntfile could not be found.
info: (no grunt tasks will be run.)
```

Actually it was from grunt, so to remove last to live , i update my .sailsrc file as give below

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "grunt": false
  }
}
```

I think this is the right way to disable grunt.